# Is it possible to google search with the gdata API?

Tags: python, gdata-api

I might be just thick (nothing new), but I can't seem to find anything related to an old-fashioned, vanilla google search in the gdata API docs. Anyone know if it's possible? (I know it probably is with a little tinkering, but I already have a Python web-scraping class created that does it for me, but I was wondering if using gdata would be the *right thing to do*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the gdata API is just for the Google Doc's application (Google Spreadsheet etc).

The search API does expose a REST interface for "Flash and other Non-Javascript Environments" though:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje